# Sugestão com arquitetura de sistema JS

Tags: javascript

Olá, tudo bom?

Atualmente eu tenho um sistema feito em AS2 que tem a funcionalidade de executar vídeos e imagens. Ela trabalha com um conceito semelhante a Maquina de estados finito.

Como o código é feito? Ele roda dentro de um enterframe, executando varias coisas a cada "passada" do laço, validando se o vídeo esta acabando, etc.

Com a "morte" do Flash e por outras questões, precisamos migrar (basicamente criar do 0) esse sistema para JS, porém, não consigo pensar numa arquitetura que consiga fazer isso.

Usar algo como setInterval em toda parte do código não me parece nem um pouco uma solução elegante. Como posso ter várias tarefas sendo executadas várias vezes?

Em geral, o que minha aplicação tem que fazer é ficar analisando toda hora se tem algo pra fazer, seja executar um download, exibir um vídeo, etc..

Bom, espero que tenha ficado claro minha dúvida. Desde já agradeço.

**Edit:** O projeto sera um player de vídeo. Enquanto toca, tenho a necessidade de ficar fazendo outras tarefas.

Como isso funciona hoje? Tenho um projeto em C que controla toda parte de hardware, exibi vídeos e gerencia download.

Minha necessidade é ter agora um projeto em JS que de tempos em tempos fique executando rotinas, tais como ver se existe algo novo pra baixar do servidor, mandar exibir um vídeo e durante esse, ficar analisando se está pra acabar, etc.

O que eu não sei fazer é como criar esse ciclo de tarefas, tipo, como fazer ele executavas minhas tarefas a cada X período. No FLASH usamos o Onenterframe, só que isso consome muito desempenho visto que ele sempre vai executar o código todo e validar se esta na hora de fazer alguma tarefa.

Comment: Fale mais sobre a sua necessidade de negócio, pois não ficou muito claro o que você precisa.

Comment: Pronto, adicionei mais algumas informações.

Comment: A saída é o `setInterval()` mesmo. `setInterval()` e `setTimeout()` são as únicas formas de se executar processos paralelos em JavaScript. Quanto ao player você pode utilizar HTML5. A API JavaScript com HTML5 é bem ampla e permite uma série de verificações sobre a execução da mídia.

Comment: Esses setInterval e setTimeout eles tem algum consumo de memoria absurdo ou até mesmo leak de memoria? 

A implementação desses recursos feito pelo AngularJS, é melhor, pior ou da na mesma? Estou fazendo testes, inicialmente usando esse setInterval mesmo, com angularjs, mas tenho medo de escolher caminhos errados..

Bom, desde já muito obrigado pela sua atenção

Comment: Não sei das implicações em se utilizar Angular, mas a performance é razoável. Se não tiver muitos processos paralelos e o intervalo não for muito pequeno o impacto é quase imperceptível. Nunca ouvi falar de leak em JavaScript.

Comment: Eu iria ter um setInterval analisando somente o exibido de vídeo, com intervalo de no maximo 1s e um outro pras demais operações

Comment: Tranquilo. Até 300ms é praticamente impeceptível a alteração na performance, desde que não altere demais o DOM ou o CSSOM, provocando um redesenho muito grande da tela.

Comment: Entendi.. amigo, muito obrigado pela suas dicas! Em relação ao DOM e CSSOM (ainda vou pesquisar pra saber o que é), vou seguir seus conselhos.

Muito obrigado pela sua ajuda!